# Why won't GraphQL (on Node.js) call my "resolve" method?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I'm trying to implement a very basic GraphQL interface in Node.js, but no matter what I do I can't seem to get the `resolve` method of my `foo` type to trigger.  When I run the following code in a unit test it runs successfully, but I can see from the (lack of) console output that `resolve` wasn't called, and as a result I get an empty object back when I call `graphql(FooSchema, query)`.

Can anyone more experienced with GraphQL suggest what I might be doing wrong?  I'm completely baffled as to how the whole operation can even complete successfully if GraphQL can't find and call the method that is supposed to return the results ...

```
const fooType = new GraphQLInterfaceType({
    name: `Foo`,
    description: `A foo`,
    fields: () => ({
        id: {
            description: `The foo's id`,
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt),
        },
        title: {
            description: `The foo's title`,
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
        }
    })
});
const queryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    fields: {
        foo: {
            args: {
                id: {
                    description: 'ID of the foo',
                    type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
                }
            },
            resolve: (root, { id }) => {
                console.log(12345); 
                return getFoo(id)
            },
            type: fooType,
        }
    },
    name: 'Query',
});

export default new GraphQLSchema({
    query: queryType,
    types: [fooType],
});

// In test:
const query = `
    foo {
        title
    }
`;
const result = graphql(FooSchema, query); // == {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const fooType = new GraphQLInterfaceType({
    name: `Foo`,
    description: `A foo`,
    fields: () => ({
        id: {
            description: `The foo's id`,
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt),
        },
        title: {
            description: `The foo's title`,
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
        }
    })
});
```

This is an interface type, however your consumer `queryType` never *implements* it. A quick solution should be to change it to this:

```
const fooType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: `Foo`,
    description: `A foo`,
    fields: () => ({
        id: {
            description: `The foo's id`,
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt),
        },
        title: {
            description: `The foo's title`,
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
        }
    })
});
```

Here's an example that works for me:

```
const {
  GraphQLNonNull,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLSchema,
  graphql,
} = require('graphql');

const fooType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: `Foo`,
  description: `A foo`,
  fields: () => ({
    id: {
      description: `The foo's id`,
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt),
    },
    title: {
      description: `The foo's title`,
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
    },
  }),
});

const queryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  fields: {
    foo: {
      args: {
        id: {
          description: 'ID of the foo',
          type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
        },
      },
      resolve: (root, { id }) => {
        return { id, title: 'some-title' };
      },
      type: fooType,
    },
  },
  name: 'Query',
});

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: queryType,
  types: [fooType],
});

graphql(schema, `{ foo (id:"123") { id, title } }`).then(console.log.bind(console));
```

This should print:

```
$ node test.js
{ data: { foo: { id: 123, title: 'some-title' } } }
```

Here's the docs on the InterfaceType: http://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: I've been copy/pasting from the Star Wars example and I must not have been paying enough attention to the types of what I'm copying.  However, changing `fooType` to be a new `GraphQLObjectType` doesn't solve my problem: my `resolve` still doesn't get called and the `graphql` call still returns an empty object :(

Comment: What does `return getFoo(id)` do exactly?

Comment: Nothing (or to be more accurate, it's irrelevant), because it never even gets called.  That's the root issue: if I could just get `graphql` to call it (via `resolve`) I'd be set.

Comment: I edited my answer to show code that works for me locally when i use this query:

`
{
  foo(id: "123") {
    id
    title
  }
}
`

Comment: Huh.  So I directly copy/pasted your code, and then I ran my test which is just `graphql(FooSchema, 'foo(id: "123") { id title })'` ... and I still get back an empty object.  When I modify your `resolve` method to do a `console.log` I see no log output.  I totally believe that your code runs on your machine though ... could there possibly any sort of environmental factor?

Comment: As a side note, if I just delete everything in my `foo:` object except the `type`, everything behaves the same.  Evidently there's a default `resolve` implementation, which explains why my/your code runs successfully even though it never runs `resolve`.  I just wish I could figure out why it won't run my `resolve` ...

Comment: OK, final edit: try running what I have in my post... this should work. Also, I'm on: `"graphql": "^0.7.2"`

Comment: That last edit worked, and when I add a `console.log` to my `resolve` it actually logs!  I'm not sure what I did differently from your code, but at least now I can work backwards and figure it out.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: There was one last problem: the last final line ... `const result = graphql(FooSchema, query);`. `graphql` doesn't return a result, it returns a promise which, when evaluated, returns a result, so I should have used `graphql(FooSchema, query).then((result) => {console.log(result)});`. Could you please add this last bit to your answer so I can accept it?